# load product in perticular category in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, category-products, navigation

I am creating navigation for my store. I am new to magento. I am having problem to load product under that category. It is possible for me to print all product under all categories but I dont know how to load products under its specific category.

This is my code

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml($this->getSelectedCategoryId(), 0, 'level-top') ?>
<?php
if ($this->getTitle() != '') {
    $title = $this->getTitle();
} else {
    $title = 'Categories';
}
?>
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
<?php if ($_menu): ?>
        <div class="block vertical-menu">   
            <div class="title-block" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><h4><?php echo $this->__($title) ?></h4></div>  
            <div class="block-content">
                <?php $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2);?>
                <ul class="content-navigation">
                    <?php foreach($children as $category){ ?>
                    <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrlPath(); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></a>
                    <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($category->getId()); //Pass category ID here.
                          $productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();?>

                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($productCollection as $product){ ?>
                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></a></li>
                        <?php }?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('mpanel')->acceptToUsePanel()): ?>
        <div class="block vertical-menu">   
            <div class="block-title"><strong><span><?php echo $this->__($title) ?></span></strong></div>    
            <div class="block-content">
                <p><?php echo $this->__('Have no categories.'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

**EDIT**

```
<div class="block-content">
                <?php $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2);?>
                <ul class="content-navigation">
                    <?php foreach($children as $category){ ?>
                    <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrlPath(); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></a>
                    <?php $categoryId = $category->getId(); ?>
                    <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
                            $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                            ->load();
                    ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($products as $product){ ?>
                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></a></li>
                        <?php }?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: you need to print product of particular category, right?

Comment: yes... correct... inside navigation

Comment: I added answer how to fetch category product, you can used that code, and it help then mark as solution so other get help.

Comment: I update answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used this code to load product collection of particular category.

```
$categoryId = 32; // Replace with you category Id    
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
          ->addCategoryFilter($category)
          ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Try this code.

Comment: Check my edit .... It prints all product i have...

Comment: @parish update code properly, so i will check.

Comment: Updated my code please check

Comment: I update my answer, please try this code.

Comment: `$categoryId` and `$category_id` needs to be same

Comment: yes, you need to pass $categoryId there.

Comment: Thankyou It worked!!

Comment: I have one more problem `<a href="<?php echo $category->getUrlPath(); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></a>` category not taking `href`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48165/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-parish).

Answer (score 0):

Following code will give you all the enabled products of the required  category. If you need both enabled and disabled products then remove the filter of status from the collection.

```
$categoryId = '4' //Your category Id

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
         ->getProductCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
         ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
         ;
       foreach($products as $product)
       {
        echo 'Product Name: ' . $product->getName() . '<br/>';
       }
```